# Strange NSNotificationCenter crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I have a problem with NSNotificationCenter. Now it crashes, but a few days ago, when I added the Notification, it worked properly. In the time between I added some code that has nothing to do with that.

I have about 10x10 tiles. Each tile adds itself as an observer as soon as it is created:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(playerJumped) name:@"TestNot" object:nil];
```

And in my player class, every time a jump ended, I post a Notification with the following code:

```
if (self.postNotifications == YES) {
    //Also post the notification for all the Tiles.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"TestNot" object:self];
}
```

If I use NSLog() in the tiles, I can see that about 3 or 4 tiles receive the notification. And after that, the application crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS. It says `objc_msgSend() selector name: playerJumped`. But I don't get why. I see that it works with the first one than it crashes.
What's my error here? Can you please help me!
Sandro

EDIT: Is there a Problem, because the Notification is received by about 100 objects?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your tile object has been deallocated but it is still registered with the notificationCenter to receive notifications. Try adding a breakpoint on the tile's -dealloc method if this isn't what you are expecting.

Comment: That's strange. I just tested it and you are right. The tile gets deallocated. But I don't know why. I'll look where this happens... xD

Comment: Great. That was it. In the time between I added the tile to a few other scenes. And in these scenes, the tiles get deallocated, but not removed as an observer. So the crash occured... Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Had the same problem myself.
Adding this to the class solved the problem

```
- (void) dealloc 
{

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

}
```